# Unlocking password-locked RCA Voyager tablet

Tags: locked-out, rca-voyager-ii

After setting up a new RCA Voyager tablet, it will not unlock and keep asking for a password. However, there was never a moment when it's asked to have a password.

How to unlock it and get the current unknown password to be deleted?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Please take a look at our [locked-out tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/locked-out/info) for first aid.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to unlock the password by following these steps:

1. Switch off the tablet
2. Press the volume up key and power key at the same time
3. After 15 seconds, the screen will turn on, showing "no command" and the Android logo
4. Press the power key, and then the screen will show some options
5. After keeping mind instruction given on the screen, go down and click on format and wipe all data, then it will show the process
6. Reboot the tablet
7. Complete the tablet's profile
8. If there's a problem of entering a wrong email address, enter the email address which was entered the first time in the tablet, and then you will be able to get access to the tablet.

Keep in mind that the whole tablet's data will be deleted when following this process – so first, back up all data after connecting the tablet with any secure PC.